# What got salisbury steak its name?

Tags: meat, steak, american-cuisine

I love salisbury steak, ever since I first tried it in Wendy's, but now I want to know exactly why it is named the salisbury steak.

What's the reason it's called a salisbury steak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Origin: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salisbury_steak#Origin_of_the_name)

[James Salisbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Salisbury) was an American physician and chemist known for his advocacy of a meat-centered diet to promote health, and the term Salisbury steak for a ground beef patty served as an entree has been used in the United States since 1897. Today, Salisbury steak is usually served with a gravy similar in texture to brown sauce, along with various side dishes. It is a common item in supermarket frozen food sections.

Dr. Salisbury recommended this recipe (somewhat different from modern Salisbury steak recipes) for the treatment of [alimentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alimentation):

> [Eat the muscle pulp of lean beef made into cakes and broiled. This pulp should be as free as possible from connective or glue tissue, fat and cartilage...previous to chopping, the fat, bones, tendons and fasciae should all be cut away, and the lean muscle cut up in pieces an inch or two square. Steaks cut through the centre of the round are the richest and best for this purpose. Beef should be procured from well fatted animals that are from four to six years old.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_V_9XiEifFAC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=%22Eat+the+muscle+pulp+of+lean+beef+made+into+cakes+and+broiled.%22&source=bl&ots=YXesp8bXoU&sig=ACfU3U1u2gepvGWDi3a9mZ19gDZ9XvnC_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig2qW_h83gAhVM7qwKHcAgAGYQ6AEwAnoECCEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Eat%20the%20muscle%20pulp%20of%20lean%20beef%20made%20into%20cakes%20and%20broiled.%22&f=false)
>
> [The pulp should not be pressed too firmly together before broiling, or it will taste livery. Simply press it sufficiently to hold it together. Make the cakes from half an inch to an inch thick. Broil slowly and moderately well over a fire free from blaze and smoke. When cooked, put it on a hot plate and season to taste with butter, pepper, salt; also use either Worcestershire or Halford sauce, mustard, horseradish or lemon juice on the meat if desired. Celery may be moderately used as a relish.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_V_9XiEifFAC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=%22Eat+the+muscle+pulp+of+lean+beef+made+into+cakes+and+broiled.%22&source=bl&ots=YXesp8bXoU&sig=ACfU3U1u2gepvGWDi3a9mZ19gDZ9XvnC_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig2qW_h83gAhVM7qwKHcAgAGYQ6AEwAnoECCEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Eat%20the%20muscle%20pulp%20of%20lean%20beef%20made%20into%20cakes%20and%20broiled.%22&f=false)